# How to filter elements with two select options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to work out why I am not able to select two level filter on this code:

```
a[data-gender=men][data-color=blue][data-color=red]
```

What I want to do is filtering the products by gender and two colors blue and red. Filtering by only one color or one gender is working fine.

```js
// find elements
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).css('background', $(this).data("color"));
  $(this).text($(this).data("gender"))
});
$("a[data-gender=men][data-color=blue][data-color=red]").removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;

}

.zoomOut{
display:none;


}
.zoomIn{
display:cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="s" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="yellow" data-size="s" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="black" data-size="s" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="l" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="khaki" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="green" data-size="l" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="s" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="s" data-gender="men"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="grey" data-size="l" data-gender="bi"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="blue" data-size="m" data-gender="women"></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default zoomOut" data-color="red" data-size="m" data-gender="men"></a>
```

Comment: `a[data-gender=men][data-color=blue][data-color=red]` says to find `a` tags that have a data-gender of men **and** a data-color of blue **and** a data-color of red.  If you want a logical or, then you need to include a secondary conditional for the second case, the two selectors separated by comma in the single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
//Use comma separated conditions for OR, so data-gender=men and data-color=blue
//OR data-gender=men and data-color=red
$("a[data-gender=men][data-color=blue], a[data-gender=men][data-color=red]").removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
```